# How to properly run ZAP against OWASP Benchmark?

Tags: security, benchmarking, owasp, zap

I'm trying now already a few weeks to run zap against the owasp benchmark properly. But I'm failing - because the results are worse than the ones of the older version of zap.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBE1U.png) is the generated Scorecard with the score my instance of ZAP 2.7 achieved. I'm really skeptical about the validity of this. 
So I thought maybe something went wrong and I repeated the benchmark, which took again almost one and a half days (not sure if this is normal as well - I own a Thinkpad 430 with a i7-3520M).

I configured zap like described in the [tips-section](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Benchmark#tab=Tool_Scanning_Tips) of the benchmarks page. At first I had problems with RAM. Because of that I upgraded to 16G (like recommended, so that shouldn't be a problem now, because I have plenty free RAM according to `free`. My OS-Details:

```
~ >>> lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    n/a
Distributor ID: ManjaroLinux
Description:    Manjaro Linux
Release:    18.0.2
Codename:   Illyria
~ >>> uname -a
Linux maksbook 4.19.13-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Dec 29 15:43:56 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux
~ >>>
```

Fortunately I didn't run into the freezing problem noted. Although I'm helpless now how to move on. Because I'm sure my measurements I did so far are wrong.

Help would be very appreciated!

Edit: 
I tried the method noted: running the a scan on each test case one by one. Unfortunately that changed nothing. I also tried to run arachni against the benchmark. It crashed the first time because of [this](https://github.com/Arachni/arachni/issues/768) error. I reconfigured arachni and restarted the scan. I will update when/if I get the results.

Edit 2:
So another try and this time I'm not sure if zap isn't the problem. This time i focus on just the path traversal vulnerabilities. And guess what - zap doesn't catch any of those(0/268 [expected by version 1.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fLI9.png) ). I set the context to all the path traversal cases(see following [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gc5Or.png)) configured the policy for only path traversal instances (even setup insane strength). Ironically zap found a few pathtraversals in other instances(full scan - default context see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbC7u.png)) 
Now I'm really disappointed. Still, I hope I do something wrong.

Comment: I've pinged one of the Benchmark project leads in case they havnt seen this. We (the ZAP core team) plan to run this against ZAP but as you've found out its non trivial to set up and we're really busy with other things :/ Be very interested to hear how you get on with this.

Comment: @SimonBennetts Thank you! I hope to get to hear from them.

Comment: Maybe you missed this part of the tips doc you linked: "NOTE: Similar to Burp, we can't simply run ZAP against the entire Benchmark in one shot. In our experience, it eventually freezes/stops scanning. We've had to run it against each test area one at a time. If you figure out how to get ZAP to scan all of Benchmark in one shot, let us know how you did it! "

Comment: @kingthorin already tried that because of my helplessness. Other than that it took an eternity compared to the "one shot" method, the results stay the same,  unfortunately. Anyway the note just claims that, they did it, because zap "freezes/stops" and I couldn't verify this with the current versions of zap

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question, I thought you had said you “did” encounter freezing/stalling... my bad.

Comment: @SimonBennetts can you explain me if I'm doing something wrong? I don't understand why ZAP can't catch any of the expected path traversals?

Comment: Try to manually explore just those test cases and run a policy with just the traversal plugin enabled? Perhaps it's just a category ZAP doesn't do well in....not sure.

Comment: @kingthorin see 2nd edit

Comment: ACK. I wish I had something further for you. Sadly I've never fired up the benchmark at all. I'll try to get to it sometime this month, but can't guarantee anything... TODO list is never ending :)

Comment: @kingthorin yeah sounds familiar). Thx very much for your intention nevertheless. I already decided to just take whats already publicly available and attach my tries with a disclaimer - it's __just__ a bachelor thesis  and I already got a ACK for a master - __just__ need to pass;)) - but some nice results wouldnt have hurt anyway